# Is it possible to have more or/and custom pin for powermap plugin in Dynamics crm?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Do you know if it's possible to have custom pin or more pin for the powermap plugin in Dynamics CRM ?

Actually I'm limited to this list:

[image]

An example of map view:
[image]

I checked here: https://www.powerobjects.com/guides/powermap/ but I don't see any information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support answered me.

Here is a post that was advised by them: https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/08/14/add-delete-pin-graphics-for-maps-in-crm/

You can do it from 2 different ways.

- In the backoffice of Dynamics CRM directly as @André Cavaca said.
- Via XrmToolBox, by using the plugin "Webressources manager" and uploading your new images in the root "pomap_" in folder "pins".

Example:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting pin image you have there

Comment: Haha, it was just to do a test ^^'

Answer (score 1):

PowerMap is a third party add-on created by PowerObjects. If there is a way to customize pins, they haven't documented it. You best bet is to reach their support team [https://uk.powerobjects.com/support/](https://uk.powerobjects.com/support//)

**EDIT:** Unsupported Workaround

You can always go to Settings -> Customizations -> Customize the System -> Web Resources, search for a display name that starts with *Pin:Bing*, open it and change its image for the one you want.